# Cocoa question: How to get file path for current open document for the front most application

Tags: cocoa, macos, document

I can get the front most application, how do I get the path for the front most document?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this for any app. Apps don't always have documents. If an app supports the standard AppleScript document model, you can do it with AppleScript. For example,

```
tell application "TextEdit"

    set foo to the path of the first document

end tell
```

Comment: Do you know any  way to do this without Apple Script, i.e. from other Cocoa application?