# How to get file paths for current open documents in a macOS project in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsdocument

I have a macOS project in Swift where I would like to get file paths for current open documents. How can this be achieved?

EDIT: I mean the open documents of the app itself. Typically represented as windows or tabs.

PS
I check these questions but don't help:
[How to get file path? Loading documents in Document based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723032/how-to-get-file-path-loading-documents-in-document-based-app)
[Cocoa question: How to get file path for current open document for the front most application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976152/cocoa-question-how-to-get-file-path-for-current-open-document-for-the-front-mos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the documents from `NSDocumentController` and the URL from each document.

```
for document in NSDocumentController.shared().documents {
    print("\(document.fileURL)")
}
```